# Is there something analogous to python's `isoweek.Week` in Java or Android?

Tags: java, android, python

`isoweek.Week` in python provides a week object that allows for simple operations such as

```
w = Week(2014,2)
print w+200
isoweek.Week(2017, 45)
```

as well as comparison operations. Is there something in Java or Android that does the same?

Comment: Take a look at the [Calender](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class or  if you are okay with using an external library, then [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to add weeks to a calendar.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,2);
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " "+ cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));

    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 200);
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " "+ cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));


}
```